# Where to start with Answer Set Programming

Tags: reference-request, logic

I'd like a recommendation from you guys. Where should I start reading and learning about Answer Set Programming. I have read a paper from Vladimir Lifschitz and Michael Gelfond, "The stable model semantics for logic programming". I'm very confused as my knowledge in this field is very scarce. I am a self-taught programmer with simple maths and logic knowledge.

Can you point me with basic references where I should start, or topics I should read, online tutorials, text-books, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend the book

*Knowledge Representation, Reasoning and Declarative Problem Solving*

by Chitta Baral. It covers both theory (syntax, semantics, expressiveness, ...) and practical (programming methodology) information. For understanding of the semantics, basic knowledge of math and logic is sufficient.

You should also google for these ASP developer's tools:

POTASSCO  (where you can also find good lecture notes)

[ASPIDE](https://www.mat.unical.it/ricca/aspide/index.html)

DLV System

[JASP: A Framework for Integrating Answer Set Programming](http://www.giovannigrasso.it/jdlv/)